# PHP Sending an html email

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to figure out what the deal is with my php headers, I am trying to send an html style email and I keep getting the script tags with it and cant seem to figure out what is going on... Maybe you guys can help me.

```
    $this->headers = 'From: no-reply@***********.com\r\n';
    $this->headers .= 'CC: $this->ccList[\'Richard\']\r\n';
    $this->headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n';
    $this->headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n';
```

The message looks like this,

```
    $this->message = '<html><body>
        <table rules="all" style="Border-Color: #666;" cellpadding="10">
        <tr style="background: #eee;"><td><strong>Dealer Code</strong></td><td style="background: #eee;">' . $dealer['dCode'] . '</td><tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Name: </strong></td><td>' . $dealer['name'] . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Address: </strong></td><td>' . $dealer['address1'] . '</td>    </tr>
        <tr><td><strong>City: </strong></td><td>' . $dealer['dCity'] . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>State: </strong></td><td>' . $dealer['dState'] . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Zip: </strong></td><td>' . $dealer['dZip'] . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Status: </strong></td><td>' . $dealer['status'] . '</td></tr>
        </table>
        </body></html>
        <p>This message has been sent because this dealer has Logged In<br/>
            If the Dealer Completes An Order A different email will be<br>
            sent to you regarding that order.</p>';
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean that you're getting script tags with it?  And, how are you sending the mail?  Why do you have a paragraph after `</html>`?

Comment: What mail client are you using to read the message and does it support HTML email messages (if it does support it which most do, is HTML support enabled)?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're single quoting your strings and your \r\n are not receiving any translation in to real newline characters.

Also, try rearranging your headers so that your mime version is first, then the content type

```
$this->headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$this->headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$this->headers .= "From: no-reply@***********.com\r\n";
$this->headers .= "CC: $this->ccList[\'Richard\']\r\n";
```